# Undefined SpeechSynthUtterance error on Firefox Android

Tags: javascript, firefox, speech-synthesis, firefox-android

### Background

I am creating a simple `SpeechSynth` component that runs fine on most devices but somehow on FireFox android the `SpeechSynthUtterance` will dispatch the `onerror` event with no [error property defined on the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/onerror#examples).

Voices are loaded; it's not an issue of undefined voices. I can't get to the bottom of this since the error is simply `undefined`.

### Reproduction

```js
const MAX_LOAD_VOICES = 5
let loadVoiceCount = 0

const loadVoices = (callback) => {
  const speech = window.speechSynthesis
  const voices = speech.getVoices()

  if (voices.length > 0) {
    return callback({ speech, voices })
  }

  if (++loadVoiceCount > MAX_LOAD_VOICES) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to load speech synthesis voices, after ${loadVoiceCount} retries.`)
  }

  return setTimeout(() => loadVoices(callback), 100)
}

loadVoices(({ speech, voices }) => {
  const utterance = new window.SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello world')
  utterance.voice = voices[0] // assume this is the voice we want
  utterance.onend = function () {
    console.log('SpeechSynth successfully ended')
  }

  utterance.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log('SpeechSynth failed')
    console.debug(event)
  }
  
  speech.speak(utterance)
})
```

### Expected

This script should run just fine (just try with your browser)

### Result on Firefox Android

The utterance.onerror event will be fired with no error defined and no text spoken.

Output of the logged error event (`console.debug(event)`):

```js
{
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
charIndex: 0
charLength: null
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
elapsedTime: 0
eventPhase: 0
explicitOriginalTarget: SpeechSynthesisUtterance { text: "Hello world", volume: 1, rate: 1, … }
isTrusted: true
name: ""
originalTarget: SpeechSynthesisUtterance { text: "Hello world", volume: 1, rate: 1, … }
returnValue: true
srcElement: SpeechSynthesisUtterance { text: "Hello world", volume: 1, rate: 1, … }
target: SpeechSynthesisUtterance { text: "Hello world", volume: 1, rate: 1, … }
timeStamp: 2591
type: "error"
utterance: SpeechSynthesisUtterance { text: "Hello world", volume: 1, rate: 1, … }
<get isTrusted()>: function isTrusted()
<prototye>: SpeechSynthesisEventPrototype { utterance: Getter, charIndex: Getter, charLength: Getter, … }
}
```

The [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance#browser_compatibility) should also be of no issue, since I am running FF Mobile 88.0.1 on Android 11

Am I missing something "special" to create the utterance?

Comment: I'm running Firefox 88.1.2. I copied your code and loaded it from an html page and it works, albeit in a South Korean voice.

Comment: Firefox 88.1.2 on android?

Comment: Yes correct. Is your code online anywhere?

Comment: That's interesting. Did you set any "flags" or settings on your FF mobile? Is it the FF nightly build? The code I used is derived from the [mdn speech synth demo](https://mdn.github.io/web-speech-api/speak-easy-synthesis/) which I used as a starting point for my dev but as you can see I did not came any further.

Comment: It's just normal FF, no specific settings set. 4 ideas: run speech.cancel() just before speech.speak(utterance). Use onvoiceschanged event to wait for the voices instead of your voice counts. Select a voice where lang starts with en instead of picking voices[0].  Have the utterance speak after user interaction e.g. button press.

Comment: @Frazer I wonder, whether this has to do with secure context? Since am using the debug tools and access my website running on another machine I have no secure context, which makes some features like service workers unavaiable. Does this maybe affect this feature but it's just not document?

Comment: When I started using speechSynthesis I had no access to https so used plain http and it was working.